# Invoke overwritten .click() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, dom-events

I have to modify a plugin for wordpress.
I have following code in a external js file:

```
jQuery(".ep_filter a").click(function(t) { // Here it sorts li elements with quicksand });
```

So this code above executes when the user clicks on an li element.

So now I want to invoke the method above when the page loaded. Because I can give a parameter to the site with the category. So i want to filter the elements.

When I execute a `click()` on the object it doesn't run the overwritten method. It just performs a normal click and navigates to the href.

Comment: Instead of creating an `anonymous` function create a function and call the `function` `onload` then just pass the `function` as an argument to the click handler...

Comment: Please show code used to call this method when the page loads. And check your console. Is it possible you have called the method before it was bound? Did you use `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()` or something to make sure that the click handler is wired up at the point that you call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include `e.preventDefault()`

```
jQuery(".ep_filter a").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault()
    // Here it sorts li elements with quicksand 

});
```

but you probably want the user to be able to click the a-links on their manual click, so you might want to think of a flag or something

---

**version 2**

I suggest sepperating what happens inside the click event in its own function. That way, you can call the function without having to rely on a click being triggerd. ie. call it from the document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    var liTarget = $(myOnloadVariable)
    quicksandSortLi(liTarget );

})

jQuery(".ep_filter a").click(function(e) { 
    quicksandSortLi($(e.target)); //send a dom-object to the quicksand function
});

function quicksandSortLi(targetLi){
    var target  = event.target //this is which li was clicked on.
    // Here it sorts li elements with quicksand
}
```

Comment: As event `e` need to be defined, I have modify the post a bit

Comment: preventDefault() is already implemented. To clear my question up: I want to simulate the click when the page is loaded. When I manually click on the item it goes all well and the items are sorted. But I don't know how to invoke the click event programmatically.

Comment: I edited my answer with a second solution. Don't hesitate to ask  about anything